# gRPC client can't connect to server Failed parsing HTTP/2, only on my computer

Tags: http, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to connect to a server from my client using gRPC, but connection always fails only on my pc(macbook pro). My teammate tried with the exact same code, and it works perfectly fine. The following is the error messages from each client and server. We are using protobuf 3, python 3.9. Can anyone give me some hint? Thank You.

Client Error Message

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Failed parsing HTTP/2"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1626678822.089372000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.113.66.145:9390", "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc", "file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","grpc_status":14}"
```

Server Error Message

```
[07/19 01:29:32 cctv_service]: Session Connected
E0719 01:29:32.744434791   14615 parsing.cc:302]             Unknown frame type 71
I0719 01:29:32.744519637   14615 chttp2_transport.cc:812]    W:0x7f3364002ae0 SERVER [ipv4:10.25.211.173:50662] state IDLE -> WRITING [CLOSE_FROM_API]
I0719 01:29:32.744554230   14615 chttp2_transport.cc:812]    W:0x7f3364002ae0 SERVER [ipv4:10.25.211.173:50662] state WRITING -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
```

Comment: Are you certain the server started successfully, and you're not connecting to another server of a different protocol sitting on the port you tried opening?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The server is well initialized, because with my teammate's pc it works just fine. And also i've double checked the port of the server and the pc using wireshark.
When the image(bytes type) included in the gRPC message size is small, the connection problem doesn't occur. I think the problem is when the image bytes is too large, overflow causes this whole problem. But it doesn't make sense either because on my test, the size limit of the image was about 60KB, but gRPC message's size limit is 4MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated MacOS 11.4 to 11.5, problem never appeared again.